# Div title does not show complete string

Tags: html, css, tooltip, chromium, gecko

I have got a problem with the code snippet below. As you can see hovering over the "Hello" should show `%Test%.Identification.CustomerNumber` as a tooltip. The problem is that the first "%" letter is not shown in the tooltip, so there is only `Test%.Identification.CustomerNumber` in the tooltip.

```css
.line-cut {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
  direction: rtl
}
```

```html
<div class="line-cut" title="%Test%.Identification.CustomerNumber">
   Hello
</div>
```

When I remove `direction: rtl` from my css it works perfectly and shows what it is supposed to. I have not found a solution or a workaround yet. I tried it with following browsers but the error occured on every browser. I listed the browsers and the versions I used in the table below

| Browser | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft Edge | 105.0.1343.33 |
| Google Chrome | 106.0.5249.62 |
| Firefox | 105.0.1 |

Can some help me to fix the problem or knows a workaround? Could this be a bug in the chromium and gecko engine? Please do not hesitate to comment for further information or questions.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Using the Unicode LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE, found [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/).

```
title="&#x202a;%Test%.Identification.CustomerNumber"
```

Comment: I tried this and it does not work unfortunately. The tooltip shows the unicode exactly as it is written in the title attribute ("&#x202a;%Test%.Identification.CustomerNumber"). "&#x202a;" is not interpreted as "%".

Answer (score 0):

you can use Left-To-Right Embedding UniCode at first of your string, Unicode Hex Character Code `&#x202a;` learn more in this [link](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-unicode-controls).

Comment: It did not work for me... "&#x202a" was exactly displayed like that. The position of the unicode was wrong as well